# Can I work for a US company (paid in USD) and live in the UK as a dependent of my spouse's Tier 2 General Visa?

Tags: uk-visa

My husband and I are US citizens. We are finishing a 5 year visa (Tier 2 ICT) through my work, where he was a dependent. I've negotiated a job back in the US with my company (will start in about a month's time).

However, now my husband has been offered a job with his company in the UK (offering a Tier 2 General visa). If my US job can be done from anywhere (remotely), once my husband's visa comes through (where I am a dependent), can I continue to work for the US office (being paid in USD) and live in the UK as his dependent? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you can, but that for reasons relating to taxation and labor law you'll need to work as a self-employed independent contractor rather than as an employee.